# Mongodb Replication error in Linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, database-replication, replicaset

I tried to configure a 3-member replica set in a single server for test deployment. When I tried to execute the command `rs.initiate()` the following error appears:

```
{
    "info2" : "no configuration explicitly specified -- making one",
    "me" : "localhostName:27017",
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "No host described in new configuration 1 for replica set rs maps to this node",
    "code" : 93
}
```

Please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: Have you read https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: That issue was resolved.Thanks!!!! The hostname was not mapped in etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

That issue was resolved. The hostname was not mapped in etc/hosts file. – Ganu